# Can't click JavaScript links with Selenium capybara

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, capybara

I've got a simple Capybara script which I am running in order to fill in a form multiple times. However I'm running into some issues when trying to click on JavaScript based links.

When I inspect element, the link looks like this:

```
<a id="s_1_1_53_0" tabindex="4997" href='JavaScript:SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm1_0,s_7,"s_1_1_53_0","")'>
Modify or cease services
</a>
```

I've tried using click_on("s_1_1_53_0"), click_link("s_1_1_53_0"), find("s_1_1_53_0").click. I've also tried using the link text etc, and running the JavaScript from the link directly, but no luck.

Page source looks like this:

```
<html  OT='SiebWebMainWindow'>
<head>
<script language="javascript">navigator.id = "1432641204";</script></head>
<script language="javascript">top._swescript = window;</script><script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/rtcEditor.js"></script><script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/swecommon_top.js"></script><script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/swecommon.js"></script><script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/navctrl.js"></script><script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/sweutil_keyboard.js"></script><a id="jsIncludes"></a>
<script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/swemessages_enu.js"></script>
<script>this.ConfirmDeleteMessage ='Are you sure you want to delete this record?'</script><script> this.focus(); </script>
<frameset rows='100%,*' border='0' frameborder='No' OnUnload=SWEUnloadApp("/start.swe","","")>
<frame name="_sweclient" title="" src="/start.swe?SWECmd=GetCachedFrame" marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' noresize scrolling='No'>
<frame name="_swe" title="" src="/start.swe?SWECmd=GetCachedFrame&" marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' noresize scrolling='No' tabindex=-1>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Any ideas on the best way to click the link?

Comment: Is the link in one of those frames? Did you switch to the frame? Capybara/Selenium only look in frame/iframe elements when explicitly told to.

Comment: It was in fact in one of the frames, have got this sorted now. Thanks!